# Get php7 to work with apache

Tags: php, apache, development-environment, macos-sierra

I am trying to set up PHP7 to work with Apache on macOS sierra. I managed to install correctly (I checked using `php -v`) but there is no **libexec** directory where php was installed. This is a problem because I need to link to this folder to get php to work with apache. I can get to `/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.6_18`. In that directory there are many more directories and files but no **libexec** directory. How do I configure Apache now?

Comment: Maybe https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/ helps.

Comment: @localheinz That did not solve the issue. thanks though